# Understanding coordinate scaling (and viewBox) in a PyQt/SVG/JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, svg, pyqt, coordinate-systems

I am working on a PyQt application that has an SVG viewer based on QWebKit. Initially the SVG file is generated by an external application ([LilyPond](http://lilypond.org)), but we want to edit the SVG in the viewer using JavaScript.

Basically it's working pretty well, but we experience a strange rounding/conversion/rastering issue we don't have a clue about: When dragging an object, `onmousemove` outputs only rasterized values for `clientX/clientY` or `pageX/pageY`. That is we can see that the event fires a number of times, and (say) `clientX` produces a series of values like `100 100 100 100 101 101 101 101 102 102 102 102` etc., the number of repetition being dependent of the zoom factor of the view.

I assume these values are not screen pixels but numbers in a unit of the SVG document and this is the source of our issue.

The `svg` element of the file looks like this:
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.2" width="210.00mm" height="297.00mm" viewBox="0 0 119.5016 169.0094">`(remember, this is generated from the external program).

I assume that the `viewBox` attribute is used to ensure that SVG coordinates are consistent with the coordinate system of the originating application (LilyPond thinks in "staff spaces", and obviously a translation of `1` in the SVG file does exactly the same as translating by 1 staff space in LilyPond. If I change the "global staff size" in LilyPond the `viewBox` attribute will get different values.)

So what I would basically need is that `clientX`(etc.) gives me floating point results instead of rounded integers.

Is there a way to make JavaScript do that?
Or would I have to do some calculations - somehow translating `clientX` (etc.) coordinates to screen pixels and then back again (taking zooming and/or hardware into account)?

I'm at a loss when trying to understand the different scaling options at the different stages...

**EDIT**
Here's some more code...
As @uli_1973 mentioned, mouse position is sustained by the clientX/-Y property:

```
svgPoint.x = event.clientX;
svgPoint.y = event.clientY;
```

To get the mouse position translated to the coordinates of the SVG we use this line of code:

```
svgPoint = svgPoint.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```

I guess the main question is, could we get a higher resolution out of this somehow? Currently the smallest possible difference in mouse movement translates into 0.15 in SVG coordinates (mm).

**EDIT2**
The whole file can be seen at
https://github.com/PeterBjuhr/frescobaldi/blob/svg-edit/frescobaldi_app/svgview/editsvg.js

The implementation of the dragging can be found in the three event handlers at the bottom of the file.
Initially (`onmousedown`) the constructor function `DraggableObject(elem, event)` (currently starting at line 219) is called. `onmousemove` the event object is passed to the `updatePositions(e)` method in line 319.
Both use the function `mousePos()` at the top of the file. And this function is where we pinpoint the problem.

When we call `event.clientX` or any of `screenX` or `pageX` we get output of the wrong resolution.
A more detailed discussion of all our observations and thoughts may be found at https://github.com/PeterBjuhr/frescobaldi/issues/21

Comment: How are you doing the dragging?  Can you show us the code?  There are several JS libraries around that will help you with this.